# multiple integral of product of logarithmic function

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I am trying to solve an integral of the form

\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{0<t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_r<1} \frac{\log^{m_0}(1-t_0)\left\{\prod\limits_{j=1}^r\log^{m_j}\left(\frac{1-t_{j-1}}{1-t_{j}}\right)\right\}\log^{m_{r+1}}(1-t_r)}{t_0t_1\cdots t_r}dt_0dt_1\cdots dt_r,
\end{align*}
where $m_j\in \{1,2,3,\cdots\},\ (j=0,1,2,\cdots,r+1).$

Comment: Well, good for you!. Did you hsve a question? What have you attempted? Where are you stuck?

Comment: For $r=0$, I was tried. It can be expressed in terms of multiple zeta values, but for $r\ \ge 1$, I don't know.